# TextView setText overlays previous formatting on textView

Tags: java, android

This is my `textView`

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(readFromFile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = reader.readLine();
arabicFont =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"hactyp.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(arabicFont);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
ssb.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),0,message.length(),0);
tv.setText(ssb);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
while(line != null) {
    if(message.equals(line)) {
        while(!("end".equals(line))) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            tv.setText(tv.getText() +" \n" + line);
        }
    }
    line = reader.readLine();
}
tv.setTextSize(24);
is.close();
}
```

Formatting done by span is getting overlayed by  tv.setText(tv.getText() +" \n" + line);
Since there is a singleText view.
Also since i am reading from a text file line by line, and appending to textView till i recieve a token, is their any better way to apply spanning in this scenario ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is it you are trying to achieve that isn't happening?

Comment: SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
ssb.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),0,message.length(),0);
tv.setText(ssb);  UnderLine is not getting reflected in the textView

Comment: Though i fixed my issue by creating temp string and adding all text and then applying span on it, but i am curious if there is any way i can add text line by line , without doing getText each time and concat it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the `SpannableStringBuilder` directly to `tv.setText();` You have to return the String from the buffer using `toString()` like this:

`tv.setText(ssb.toString());`

You also have to use `toString()` when calling `getText()` on a TextView. So you would call that like this:

`tv.getText().toString()`